# selectmenu plugin on selectlist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `selectmenu() plugin` on the select list

```
          <select id="main" size="1"><option ..</select>
          $("#main").selectmenu();
```

Now after applying this plugin,  select list event 'onchange`is not working on the`select#main`.Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: Have you checked for an `On Select` event in the selectmenu plugin's documentation?  Because its there: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <select id="main" size="1"><option ..</select>
      $("#main").selectmenu({
        select: function(evt){ 
         // your code here on select

        }
      });
```

When using plug-in's like this, the original way of doing things in HTML will most likely be disabled and will have to be applied with-in the plug-in, so it acts properly with all it's other functionality.  In addition to my comment though, you may want to read up on the documentation to get more familiar with using it.

Comment: can u please tell me how to set any value selected in the selectlist, i tried `$("#main").selectmenu("value", "newvalue");` but not working

Comment: you're trying to add a value to it or change the value or choose an option through code?

Comment: change the selected value of the selectlist

Comment: not too familiar, but try three ways..

1. `$("#main").val('optionvaluetoselect');`
2. `<option value="Medium" selected="selected">Medium</option>`
3. `$("#main").selectmenu('select','option');` <-try the option value also if option doesn't work.